# Highlighted Items in reyclerview lose their state when scolling

Tags: android-recyclerview, highlight, selecteditem

I am trying to highlight clicked items in recylerview but as soon as when you scroll the highlighted items do not stay highlighted anymore. I do not know how to keep their state when scrolling. The implementation in the adapter class and given below:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyHolder>{
boolean isEnable = false;
List<ItemFiles> selectList = new ArrayList<>();


public MyAdapter.MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout._main,parent,false); 
   return new MyViewHolder(view);

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int
        position) {   

 holder.item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isEnabled) {
                    ClickItem(holder);
                }
}
 private void ClickItem(MyHolder holder) {
        ItemFiles s = files.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        if (holder.highlightItem.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
            holder.highlightItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.highlightItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            selectList.add(s);

            // this is what I tried to keep the highlighted state but no result

            selectList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setSelected(true);
        } else {
            holder.highlightItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.highlightItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            selectList.remove(s);
            selectList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setSelected(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to check  whether your item is already in  `selectList` during `onBindViewHolder` and alter views state accordingly

Comment: Could you state some code to clear that would be really helpful